# Using Multi-Target Image Catalog

Tags: xcode, assets, target

My app has various targets, since the identical app is used by various clients, each with its own branding.

In my Image Asset Catalog I have image sets such as:

Client123_LoginBackground

ClientABC_LoginBackground

ClientBFG_LoginBackground

etc.

So, in my app where I set this background, how do I tell my app which image set to use?

Can I somehow use the target name to do this?

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"{ClientABC}_LoginBackground"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add a preprocessor macro to your project and define its value based on each target which identifies different clients:

[image: Preprocessor macro]

2) Make sure you do this for all the relevant targets and all the environments.

3) Create something like this:

```
#define NSStringize_helper(x) #x
#define NSStringize(x) @NSStringize_helper(x)

+ (NSString *)clientName
{
#ifndef CLIENT_TYPE
  #error CLIENT_TYPE is not defined
#endif

  return NSStringize(CLIENT_TYPE);
}
```

4) Now you can easily do this:

```
NSString *imageNameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_LoginBackground", self.class.clientName];
[UIImage imageNamed:imageNameString];
```

Comment: Is there a way to determine which image scale (1x, 2x, 3x etc) was selected in each case?

Comment: I don't think so, what are you trying to achieve? The idea behind the image scale is that you don't have to know which one was selected, it depends on the device, you are always sure it will be the right image scale for the device in question. If you really want to identify devices, there are ways to do it, like [this](https://gist.github.com/Jaybles/1323251)

Comment: I'm trying to debug for possible reasons why it doesn't work. The background worked as expected, but now I'm failing to get the same to work for a UIImageView showing the logo.

Comment: O.k, turns out you can't assign an image to a UIImageView during initialization, moved it to ViewDidLoad and it worked. Thanks again!

Comment: Good point, if your image view is a reference to an element created in Interface Builder (`IBOutlet`), they are not ready during `init` methods, you can check this by putting a breakpoint in it and try to print it in the console with `po self.yourImageView`, it will be nil. You can set its image during `viewDidLoad` like you mentioned, or in `awakeFromNib`.